# Giffy's website content and copyright law

Tags: united-states, copyright, internet

I was wondering how a website like Giffy doesn't have any copyright problems, or trials from movie and tv-show productions offices, since it generates milions of dollars of incomes with small parts of those movies and tv-shows ?

Sorry in advance if my question is not formulated very well, I hope it's understandable anyway.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: they adhere to the DMCA as platform?!

Comment: It's not really clear that this would be copyright infringement automatically. GIFs like this are typically just a few frames of poor quality material, used for meme purposes, basically. No one would watch a GIF as a substitute for watching the movie, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !